# Display list before filtering

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mvvm

Well I have this code:

```
   private string employee = "";
    public string Employee
    {
        get => employee;
        set
        {
            employee = value;
            Employees = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Firstname.StartsWith(Employee) || x.Lastname.StartsWith(Employee)).ToList();
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Employee));
        }

    }
    private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get => employees;
        set
        {
            employees = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Employees));
        }
    }
```

This is working so far. If the user types in an F every employee starting with F is displayed. If the user removes the F from the textbox every Employee is displayed but if the user starts the application it shows an empty listbox. When the user starts the application every Employee should be displayed in the textbox

Comment: Move loading employees into dedicated method then you can control when to load them. You can move it into the command, so you can call it when search text is changed. or when application starts.

Answer (score 0):

use the private variable so replace:

```
        Employees = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Firstname.StartsWith(Employee) || x.Lastname.StartsWith(Employee)).ToList();
```

by:

```
        Employees = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Firstname.StartsWith(employee) || x.Lastname.StartsWith(employee)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

with this:

```
 private List<Employee> employees = db.Employees.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Load *all* employees when the class gets constructed -

```
public class MyCoolViewModel
{
    public MyCoolViewModel()
    {
        this.Employees = db.Employees.ToList();   // load all employees here
    }
    
    private string employee = "";
    public string Employee
    {
        get => employee;
        set
        {
            employee = value;
            Employees = db.Employees.Where(x => x.Firstname.StartsWith(Employee) || x.Lastname.StartsWith(Employee)).ToList();
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Employee));
        }

    }
    
    private List<Employee> employees;   // removed initialization from here
    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get => employees;
        set
        {
            employees = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(nameof(Employees));
        }
    }
}
```